# How to display kannada fonts using TFT display

Tags: python

Can anyone suggest me how to display **Kannada** fonts using TFT display.

How do I convert English to Kannada fonts?

Answer (score 2):

This may help (source - [Kannada Fonts for Linux (Ubuntu)](http://atech-adda.blogspot.com/2011/02/kannada-fonts-for-linux-ubuntu.html))

> Searching Kannada fonts for Ubuntu. I have recently installed Ubuntu
>   8.04 and faces issues with Kannada fonts, the kannada fonts are not rendered properly on firefox.
>
> 1. Uninstall free fonts that came with ubuntu which is main cause for most of the font problems.
>
>    `cd /usr/share/fonts/truetypesudo rm -rf free-fonts`
> 2. Install the kannada fonts which may or may not have installed on your Ubuntu by default.
>
>    `sudo apt-get install ttf-kannada-fonts`
> 3. Mallige fonts will be installed in `ttf-kannada-fonts` directory, which does not render properly, remaining fonts will be enough for
>      working with kannada on Ubuntu. So removed Mallige fonts.
>
>    `cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-kannada-fonts`
>
>    `rm -f Malige-*.*`
>
> Update the font cache by running the below command
>
> ```
> sudo fc-cache -fv
> ```
>
> Done...!